# Oracle SQL custom grouping / renaming with SELECT

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, cursor, alias

Using: SQL Developer 18 with Oracle 11g Enterprise DB.

I have a `select` query that I'm converting return values with a `case` statement so that I can group them how I want them (below)

```sql
    select
        case
            when activitygroup like '%Act1' then 'ThisGroup'
            when activitygroup like '%Act2' then 'ThisGroup'
            when activitygroup like '%Act3' then 'ThisGroup'
            when activitygroup like '%OtherAct1' then 'ThisGroup'
            when activitygroup like '%OtherAct2' then 'ThisGroup'
            when activitygroup like '%OtherAct3' then 'ThatGroup'
            when activitygroup like '%DifferentAct1' then 'OtherGroup'
            when activitygroup like '%DifferentAct2' then 'OtherGroup'
        else
            activitygroup
        end activitygroup
    from
        sometables....
```

There may be a better way of structuring this, if so I'd be grateful for advice.  However, what I'd actually like to do, is have the wildcard parameters (masks) and the re-assigned names in a table so that the table can be updated as required and the code can be dynamic instead of hard-coded like this.

I was thinking about looping through a cursor to the mask table and building the statement accordingly but my complete SQL statement is too long for a dynamic string (it's made up of several `UNION` queries).

What is the best way (or any practical way) of approaching this?  Thanks.

Comment: What version of Oracle?  Can you edit your question and add an appropriate version tag like `oracle12c` please.  If you are on a recent version, you could create a virtual column that uses a user-defined function that does you mapping.  Older version, you could create a view with a similar `case` expression.

Comment: First line of question states version, 11g but have added tag also.  Will explore your suggestion. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, missed that.  I am a tag fanatic...

Comment: I hope those "likes" in the sample query aren't representative of your actual data.  Otherwise, anything that's like '%OtherAct1' and '%DifferentAct1' would have previously been like like '%Act1', so you would never get the values for '%OtherAct%' and '%DifferentAct%'.

Comment: You're correct, poor form in my example.  In reality, the terms are completely unique.

Comment: So, I don't think I asked the question correctly because this was much easier than I'd assumed.  Storing the masks in a table, I can simply use LIKE to match the column I'm joining with the mask.  I didn't expect LIKE to work with the wildcard stored in a table field.